# How to add a dropdown list inside the comment dialog in google doc

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am working on a .NET web application, where google doc will be embedded in pages. When users want to post a comment in the google doc, they will need to first choose a category from a dropdownlist. This way, I plan to tag/categorize the comments. I wonder if this is possible.

Comment: _"I wonder if this is possible."_? Yes [**it's possible**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&ei=RRC-XK6_C7WP1fAP1PiK-A0&q=google+docs+drop+down). What have you tried that is not working?

Comment: @VC.One I want this within comment dialog. The search you provided doesn't help. Thanks anyways.